# Hooking up a build tool in Cabal (Haskell)

Tags: haskell, build, compiler-construction, cabal, bnfc

I was trying to use `bnfc` tool to generate a bunch of files, like lexer, parser, etc. for me. This works fine. Now I wanted to clean this up a bit by not having to manually compile the `bnfc` file and having it generate a number of files which clutter my `/src` folder.

I tried the Cabal mechanism where you list the tool in `build-tools` field of the `.cabal` file and mention the files you expect to be generated by `extra-source-files` field. This worked for me for Alex and Happy as they are recognised as  build-tools by Cabal but `bnfc` isn't. Is there a way I can hook up `bnfc` or any tool in general with Cabal and have Cabal recognise them as build-tools?

Comment: Here is an issue about adding support for BNFC to Cabal: https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/6726

Answer (score 3):

Apparently cabal doesn't know about bnfc (doesn't appear on [the list](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/blob/master/Cabal/Distribution/Simple/Program/Builtin.hs)).

Looks like there's no way to do it using just the .cabal file, but there's an example of how to hook up a preprocessor in your `Setup.hs` in the [cabal sources under tests/PackageTests/CustomPreProcess/Setup.hs](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/blob/4004b2c38c1e412a84b7ff3e895bb6a61131184b/Cabal/tests/PackageTests/CustomPreProcess/Setup.hs) using the user hook `hookedPreProcessors` (all hooks are in [UserHooks.hs](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/blob/75db3da256f4f413c0d9fdd7b74d00b36d9533c7/Cabal/Distribution/Simple/UserHooks.hs))